# Product Description text currently not “responsive.” in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, wysiwyg

I'm having a bit of trouble with the Shoppers theme. The Product description text is not re-sizing responsively on mobile devices. I attached HTML 5 extension in WYSIWYG editor .Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please contact the theme vendor about bugs in a commercial theme.